# What is the best open source VPN client?

Tags: vpn

I would like to setup a VPN server can I check whatopen source client I can install?

Answer (score 7):

[OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) is quite popular and runs on [many platforms](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/341-openvpn-compatibility.html) (Windows, Linux, BSD, Solaris, MacOS).